# 2 or more keys pressed at the same time

Tags: java, android

Hi guys I have been working with android recently and it's fine until now.

When I want to handle a key down event I just override the onKeyDown method in my activity. The same with the key up event.

The problem is that this just works for a single key, if I press to keys at the same time just one is handle.

For example:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
    boolean returnValue = super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    switch(keyCode){
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A:
            //Do something awesome here
        return true;

        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_C:
            //Do something even more awesome here
        return true;
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

If I press 'A' and 'C' at the same time one is processed first.

My first idea was to set flags with the onKeyDown event to keep the track of what keys are pressed and clear the flags with the onKeyUp event, but this failed when I switch between activities.

Now what I want is something like the following:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
    boolean returnValue = super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    switch(keyCode){
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A:
            if(/* C is pressed */){
                //Do something not so awesome here
            }
            else{
                //Do something awesome here
            }
        return true;

        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_C:
            if(/* A is pressed */){
                //Do something not so awesome here
            }
            else{
                //Do something even more awesome here
            }
        return true;
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that this just works for a single key, if I press to keys at the same time just one is handle.

That is because Android does not support multiple simultaneous keypresses, except with standard "meta" keys (e.g., shift).

Comment: I've written a test app, mashed a bunch of keys, and received all of the appropriate key down/up events, even across Activities. So, I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "Android does not support multiple simultaneous keypresses."

Comment: @Jason LeBrun: I mean that multiple simultaneous keypresses are not reported as a single `KeyEvent`, which seemed to be what the OP was seeking.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple keypress detection is often dictated by hardware limitations. Many keyboards are designed using a matrix approach, such that it's not always possible to uniquely detected keys pressed.

If you're on a device that will detect multiple keypresses, you can try storing your keydown flags in a static area, or in an object that you can pass between activities.

But keep in mind that ultimately, your solution's effectiveness will be limited by the hardware keyboard implementation.